# Convert To Double

Tags: c#

Ok im sitting with this issue kind of stupid but I don't know how to google this for the solution.

Lets say i have a database with values inside `e.g 1000.00` .

I convert it to double using `Convert.ToDouble()`;

On my PC it works, however on my server it doesn't unless I change to string and replace `.` with `,` .

**i.e** 1000,00 works on the Server but not 1000.00

But if I do Convert 1000,00 to Double I cannot save it again in the database without taking it back to string and replace , with .

How can I overcome this problem.
OS is win7, server is SQL Server 2012.

```
DataTable DT = SQLServer.ExecuteQueryWithResults("EXEC CalculateMonthlyBallance");
            foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
            {
                ClientCompany CC = Data.Companies.First(C => C.CompanyID == row[0].ToString());
                Finance Saldo = new Finance(CC.CompanyID, "Monthly Saldo", "Monthly Saldo", 0, 0, new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1), F_Type.Saldo, -1);
                double rv = row[3].ToDouble();
                MessageBox.Show("Company ID : " + CC.CompanyID.ToString() + " " + rv.ToString());
                if (rv > 0)
                {
                    Saldo.Debit = rv;
                }
                else if (row[3].ToDouble() < 0)
                {
                    Saldo.Credit = -rv;
                }

                MessageBox.Show(Saldo.Debit + " " + Saldo.Credit);
                CC.Finances = RetrieveFinances(CC.CompanyID).ToList();
                if (CC.Finances.Count(S => (S.F_Type == F_Type.Saldo) && (S.Date == new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1))) == 0)
                {
                    CC.Finances.Add(Saldo);
                    CaptureFinancial(Saldo);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Show your code. But my guess is it's probably a localization setting that's different on the server, different locales format large numbers differently.

Comment: Sounds like a localization problem. Is the server in a different country?

Comment: If they're doubles in the database, why are you parsing them as strings at all? Avoid the string conversions.

Comment: I think the main problem is that the server saves double values in a text field. Perhaps you can change that and get rid of your problems?

Comment: The problem is the Region Settings
in your pc you have the dot as separator for the number, in the server is the comma.

Comment: Assuming you use a `DataReader`: `double myVal = reader.GetDouble(index);`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: No it isn't saved in the db as text, however when I Convert.ToDouble from the Datareader and I display the object value in a message box it contains a comma instead of a dot, I've had this issue on windows 8 with excel whereby I couldnt use a dot as a seperator strange tho, problem solved with the reader.GetDouble im also guessing its localization but the server is in the same country and localization settings are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The locale setting, specifically the regional settings that govern what symbol is used as a decimal point, are influencing the conversion. To avoid that, you need to perform a culture invariant conversion so that the locale setting on your machine does not play a part. For example:

```
double value = double.Parse(stringValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That said, I do wonder why you are storing floating point values as strings in the first place. It's best to convert user input into its natural form at the earliest possible moment, and only convert back to string as late as possible.

Comment: Or you need to avoid the string conversion in the first place, which is what I'd suggset.

Answer (score 5):

See [Convert.ToDouble(string,CultureInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s9ak971%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This is because of your CultureInfo. Apparently, your PC is using periods for decimal notation, while your server is using commas. if you try to convert one of them using the other method, you get this issue.

Solution: `Convert.ToDouble()` has an extra overload which allows you to pass a cultureInfo for conversion. Or you can just save your variable in the database as a float or decimal.